# Съезжает блок если ширина не задана точно

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть блок

```
   .content {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        height:100px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        background-color: #22dd66;
        max-width: 750px;
        position: relative;
        color: #5d5d5d;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }
```

В такой ситуации блок не по центру,а ближе к правому краю прижат,но стоит задать вместо `max-width` просто `width` все норм и блок по центру.Предполагаю,что проблема в меню,которое над данным блоком.Вот весь код https://jsfiddle.net/3sp3fgs9/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Задайте `.main { overflow: hidden; }` либо примените *clearfix* т.к внутри находятся плавающие блоки `.wrapplogo { float: left; }`.
2. Помещать `div` внутрь `ul` (а не `li`) не правильно.

```css
/*-------menu------------*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,greek,vietnamese,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic);
@font-face {
    font-family: PFDinDisplayPro-Light; /* Имя шрифта */
    src: url(fonts/pfdindisplaypro-light.ttf); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
   }
  
a{text-decoration:none;}
.cbp-hrmenu {
 width: 100%;
 background-color:#183d61;
 //font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-family:PFDinDisplayPro-Light;
 position:relative;
}

/* general ul style */
.cbp-hrmenu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

/* first level ul style */
.cbp-hrmenu > ul,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {
 width: 100%;
 /*text-align:center;*/
 text-align:right;
 /*max-width: 88em;*/
 max-width: 1350px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 /*padding: 0 1.875em;*/
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a {
 font-weight: 700;
 /*padding: 1em 2em;*/
 padding: 1em 0.5em;
 color: #ffffff;
 display: inline-block;
 //font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-family:PFDinDisplayPro-Light;
}
/*.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ffb732;
}*/
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a::before,
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a::after {
 display: inline-block;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -ms-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -o-opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
 -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
 transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a::before {
 margin-right: 10px;
 content: '[';
 -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
 -o-transform: translateX(20px);
 transform: translateX(20px);
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a::after {
 margin-left: 10px;
 content: ']';
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
 -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
 transform: translateX(-20px);
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before,
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a:hover::after,
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a:focus::before,
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a:focus::after {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-opacity: 1;
    -ms-opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
 -o-transform: translateX(0px);
 transform: translateX(0px);
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen a{
 color: #fff; 
}
/*----Эффект при наведении------*/
.cbp-hrsub-inner ul li a:hover {
margin-left:7px;
}
.cbp-hrsub-inner ul li a {
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
}
/* sub-menu */
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 /*background: #183d61;*/
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 background-color: rgba(24, 61, 97,.77);
}
.cbp-hropen .cbp-hrsub {
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 z-index:11;
 border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
 z-index: 9000;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div {
 width: 33%;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 2em 0;
 text-align:left;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:before,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
 clear: both;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div a {
 line-height: 2em;
}

.cbp-hrsub h4 {
 color: #ffb732;
 padding: 0.7em 0 0.5em;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 117%;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;

}


.iconmenu{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:4px;
right:5px; 
z-index: 1;
}





.container > header {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 70em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 1.875em 3.125em 1.875em;
}

.container > header {
 padding: 2.875em 1.875em 1.875em;
}

.container > header h1 {
 font-size: 2.125em;
 line-height: 1.3;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.container > header span {
 display: block;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.5em;
 padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}

.container > header nav {
 float: right;
}

.container > header nav a {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 2.5em;
 height: 2.5em;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: transparent;
 margin: 0 0.1em;
 border: 4px solid #47a3da;
 text-indent: -8000px;
}
/*-----Logo---------------*/
.logo{
     width: 100%;
}
   
.wrapplogo{
position:relative;
width:auto;
float:left;
height:52px;
width: 171px;
padding-top: 12px;
/*margin-left: 10%;*/
}
/*----------------------------Мобильный-------------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a { padding: 1em 0.7em;}} }
@media screen and (max-width: 1350px) { 

/*cbp-hrmenu > ul,.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {max-width: 85em !important;}
.wrapplogo {width:19%;margin-left: 7px;}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a { padding: 1em 1.5em;}*/

}
@media screen and (max-width: 1290px) { 
.wrapplogo {margin-left: 7px;}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a { font-size:88%; padding: 1.4em 0.5em;}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1170px) { 
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a { padding: 2em 0.3em;font-size:75%;}
.wrapplogo{padding-top: 17px;}
.wrapplogo{width: 141px;}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 1077px) { 
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a { font-size:70%;}
.wrapplogo{width: 137px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) { 
#ulmenu{display:none;
border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
background-color:#183d61;
position:absolute;
z-index: 9999;
text-align: center;

}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a { font-size:100%;}
.iconmenu{
display:block;

position:absolute;
top:11px;
}
.wrapplogo {
    width: auto;
 float: none !important;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
 width:202px !important;
}

 /*.cbp-hrmenu {
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
 }*/

 .cbp-hrmenu > ul,
 .cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  
 }

 .cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {
  padding: 0 2em;
  font-size: 77%;
 }

 .cbp-hrmenu > ul > li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47a3da;
 }

 .cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a { 
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
 }

 .cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub { 
  position: relative;
 }

 .cbp-hrsub h4 {
  padding-top: 0.6em;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) { 
 .cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  padding: 0 2em;
 }
}
.open {
display:block !important;
}

/*------------------*/
.content {
    display: block;
  /* width: 85%; */
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100px;
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    /* margin: 21px auto; */
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #22dd66;
    max-width: 750px;
    position: relative;
    color: #5d5d5d;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="main">
<img src="img/icon/menu.png" class="iconmenu">
    <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
     <ul id="ulmenu"><div class="wrapplogo"><a href="index.php" class="logolink"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a></div>
    
      <li>
       <a href="#">1</a>
       <div class="cbp-hrsub">
        <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
         <div>
          <h4></h4>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#remont_lubouy_slojnosti" class="uslitemlink">2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#remont_electriki" class="uslitemlink">3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#computernya_diagnostika" class="uslitemlink">4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#ustanovka_signalizaciy" class="uslitemlink">5</a></li>
          </ul>
          
         </div>
         <div>
          <h4></h4>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#malarnya_kuzovnye_rabotu" class="uslitemlink">6</a></li>
           <li><a href="#razval_sxojdenya" class="uslitemlink">Развал схождения</a></li>
           <li><a href="#vukyp_auto" class="uslitemlink">Выкуп автомобилей</a></li>
           <li><a href="#svarka_argonom" class="uslitemlink">Сварка аргоном</a></li>
          </ul>
          
         </div>
         <div>
          <h4></h4>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#evakuacia_auto" class="uslitemlink">Эвакуация автомобиля</a></li>
           <li><a href="#regulirovka_sveta_far" class="uslitemlink">Регулировка света фар</a></li>
           <li><a href="#shinomontaj" class="uslitemlink">Услуги шиномонтажа</a></li>
           <li><a href="#xranenue_koles" class="uslitemlink">Хранение колес</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         
        </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
       </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
      </li>
      
       <li><a class="linkzapchasti" href="catalog.php">Автомагазин</a></li>
        <li><a class="linkbydetails" href="by_details.php">Б/У запчасти</a></li>
       <li><a class="" href="">3</a></li>
       <li><a class="linkourworks" href="ourworks.php">1</a></li>
       <li><a class="linknews" href="news.php">1</a></li>
                <li><a class="linkconstructor" href="constructor.php">1</a></li>
   
      
     
      <!--<li>
       <a href="#">Подготовка к ТО</a>
       <div class="cbp-hrsub">
        <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
         <div>
          <h4>1</h4>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 4</a></li>
          </ul></div>
          
          <div><h4>2</h4>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 3</a></li>
          </ul></div>
         
          <div><h4>3</h4>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 5</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Услуга 6</a></li>
          </ul>
          
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>-->
     
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  
  </div>


<div class="content">h
</div>
```